# Basic authentication with remote server from Local HTML file

Tags: html, ajax, cross-domain, basic-authentication

I need to perform a `Basic Authentication` with one of the servers. I have to do this from a HTML which is there on my local
system (`file://some.html`). I assume that AJAX will not work due to Cross Domain Origin restrictions (It might work if I set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header at my target end. I do not have access to that domain to do this).
Assume that I have the user id and password to authenticate with target server. How do I programmatically verify if this user id and password is correct or not? If AJAX was possible, I just need to check if the response code is 200 after sending the Base64 encoded authorization information in the header. Is it possible to verify userid and password using `IFRAMEs`?